Creating internal hyperlinked table of contents through the Word COM in Matlab
I have created a script in Matlab that processes several data channels into figures and produces a Word doc and PDF filled with the figures pasted into it. This produces a fairly large word document with several different sections. I am using the Word COM through the actxserver function to create this document. In it I set up a table of contents using the following 4 lines:
rang = word.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
word.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(rang);
word.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Format = 0;
word.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Item(1).Update;
This produces a suitable table of contents, however, I also want this table of contents to act as internal hyperlinks to there respective sections. I have spent quite a while on this and have found several possible methods that didn't work. Has anyone tried to do something like this before and managed to get the hyperlinks working in the generated Word Doc and (if possible in the PDF saved from the Word Doc.
Any help will be appreciated
word.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.UseHyperlinks = true;
I expected this to work because as far as I can find this is the documented command.

Just looking around Windows Word (without MatLab), when a TOC is generated by a field code, you generally need \ \h (backslash-h) in that code to make each entry in the TOC hyperlink. ActiveDocument.TablesOfCOntents(1).UseHyperlinks(1) = True does not appear to introduce a backslash-h, whereas if you do ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(rang,,,,,,,,,True) when you create the TOC, Word does insert the backslash-h. If I save that as .PDF I get hyperlinks to the headings...

...Without the backslash-h, I get hyperlinks from the page numbers in the TOC to the headings when working in Word, but not when exported to PDF. I suspect that this property is described as having an effect when the document is "saved to the Web" (i.e.HTML) and that may have had an effect at one time. Not sure it does now, but it may be affected by other "save to web" settings.

Hi @jonsson this was helpful so thank you. What I found that worked well was instead of trying to write the commands in MATLAB and such having to convert the VBA into a compatible format for MATLAB, was rather to just write a VBA macro that created the TOC and made it hyperlinks and then call this macro in my MATLAB script. This way I can do the data processing I need to in MATLAB and then simply call the VBA commands that I couldn't convert, as macros. This solved my problem entirely.
